# Orchard CMS - Remove the publish date & time page

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am new in orchard CMS... and I want to remove the publish date & time any one please tell me about that i am very thankful...below was the content want to remove...

publish date , time , user name ( Nov 20 2013 , 12:46 AM  ,    admin )

thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase the question, I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, the most common way is to remove the metadata shape from your alternate. In your Placement.info (e.g. in your Theme), put something like this:

```
<Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
```

You can read more here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info